# Android 2.2: Autostart application on boot problem

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, boot

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

 Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
 context.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

I have made a class that extends BroadCastreciever. I want it to run my main class on startup, but i keep getting the "force close" message when i boot my device. I think the problem is located at "YourActivity.class".

I have tried with "TestMain.class" (my main class name) and "com.test.Testmain.Class". Did i miss something?

Thanks

Comment: Paste the logcat output after the crash.

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml looks like this: <receiver android:name="BroadcastRec">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>

Comment: Is this correct? Where do I find the logcat output? Sorry but I started making apps yesterday

Comment: @Johan: First, use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your "Force Close". Second, do not start an activity from a `BroadcastReceiver` (especially at boot time), as that is exceptionally impolite. Third, if you only "started making apps yesterday", I humbly suggest that you gain more Android development experience before playing around with `BOOT_COMPLETED`.

Comment: when i added myintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); it worked. Got an explanation for that? When i googled around on how to run an app on startup, everyone says that you should do it that way. Why is it not a good idea? Is there any other ways? Thanks

Comment: You really shouldn't run an app at startup.  You *certainly* shouldn't be launching an activity at startup.  That is crazy.  What you are going to do is make it so that at some point after the user turns on their device and the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcasts are going on in the background (but they are not aware of this), your activity will suddenly pop up in their face.  This is probably not a good experience for your users.  (And as CommonsWare says, BOOT_COMPLETED is not a good place to start for app development.  Apps should *only* use this for certain special cases.)

Comment: Well, this app that im making is going to run on android tablets in kiosk mode. And if the device reboots, I want it to startup the kiosk app automatically. The tablets are going to be located at (mostly) unmanned places, thats why i want it to start automatically. Still a bad idea to do it this way? And whats the difference between starting an app and an acticity? Isnt this activity starting an app? :) Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I would follow this example if you want to start it up on boot up.

[Auto Start app](http://www.androidsnippets.com/autostart-an-application-at-bootup)

Comment: Hmnm waste of time answering this with a guy that has 25% acceptance and this question was asked in Dec last year...maybe at least I might get some up votes or help someone else with the same question.